# convert string to model in Rails rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to run a quick rake task on all my Rails models but haven't been able to call them because this piece of code tells me that I can't call the method `columns` on a string.

I tried `classify` instead of `camelize` and it hasn't worked either, tried inserting a `class_eval` in there as well, but that dosen't seem to work here / don't know too much about it.

```
task :collect_models_and_field_names => :environment do

models = Dir.glob("#{models_path}/*").map do |m|
  m.capitalize.camelize.columns.each { |n| puts n.name }
end
```

I do know that this worked so I would have manual access to the model if I needed, but I don't really want to do that...

```
  Model.columns.each { |c| puts c.name }
```

Comment: @Steph Rose & Jiří Pospíšil & , when you use constantize, Rails tells me that it expected the model file to define the Model. This probably has to do with the fact that it hasn't been called yet...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
Kernel.const_get(m.classify).columns
```

Answer (score 3):

`classify` just changes the string to look like a class -- i.e. with a capital letter and in camelcase, singular.

after using `classify` to make the string look like a class/model, you need to use `constantize`, which actually takes the string and converts it into a class.

See: 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-constantize

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
models = Dir[Rails.root.join("app", "models", "*.rb")].map do |m|
  model = File.basename(m, ".rb").classify.constantize
  model.columns.each { |n| puts n.name }
end
```